# How to setup "pathMappings" for Laravel project in VS Code

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

My Laravel project is setup in VS Code. This project is setup to use Homestead/Vagrant. I'm trying to setup the launch.json file, but I can't figure out how the pathMappings must be setup:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/path/on/server": "${workspaceRoot}/local/path"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I set: `/path/on/server`?

How do I set: `${workspaceRoot}/local/path`?

Comment: You have defined both already: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead

```
folders:
    - map: ~/code/project1
      to: /home/vagrant/code/project1
```

Comment: Can you show me, based on your example , what the "pathMappings" syntax will be in launch.json file.

Comment: An example can be: `pathMappings": {
  "/var/www/laravel": "C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\laravel"}`

Comment: This is taken from my Homestead.yaml file: folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/php_projects/BuildAid/BuildAidProject/public

Comment: Based on the information from the Homestead.yaml file, what must the pathMappings be?

Comment: Fred, check this post. It worked perfectly for me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685952/debugging-laravel-application-on-vscode