# Debugging Laravel application with Visual Studio Code opens up file listing

Tags: laravel, debugging, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to setup debugging environment for my Laravel application following this guide [Debugging Laravel application on VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685952/debugging-laravel-application-on-vscode)

However, all I get when I launch the debugger is a list of files displayed in Chrome, for some reason it is not launching index.php. How do I fix this?

[image]

Here's my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Launch & Debug",
            "configurations": [
                "Listen for Xdebug",
                "Launch Chrome against localhost"
            ]
        }],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/public",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:5500/public",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public",
            "breakOnLoad": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: remove \public from webRoot and cwd `${workspaceFolder}/public`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work - same outcome